# Code example for non-unique namespace-qualified lookup

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

Definition of S(X,m) is the following sec. 3.4.3.2/2:

> For a namespace X and name m, the namespace-qualified lookup set S(X,
>   m) is defined as follows: Let S (X, m) be the set of all declarations
>   of m in X and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1). If S (X, m) is
>   not empty, S(X, m) is S (X, m); otherwise, S(X, m) is the union of
>   S(Ni , m) for all namespaces Ni nominated by using-directives in X and
>   its inline namespace set.

The quote from 3.4.3.2/3:

> Given X::m (where X is a user-declared namespace), or given ::m (where
>   X is the global namespace), if S(X, m) is the empty set, the program
>   is ill-formed. Otherwise, if S(X, m) has exactly one member, or if the
>   context of the reference is a using-declaration (7.3.3), S(X, m) is
>   the required set of declarations of m. Otherwise **if the use of m is
>   not one that allows a unique declaration to be chosen from S(X, m),
>   the program is ill-formed.**

Can you get an example to demonstrate the rule:

> if the use of m is not one that allows a unique declaration to be
>   chosen from S(X, m), the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Does my answer make sense? Any questions?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Yes, I have one question. Please see the comment to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The draft standard actually provides an example although it is not very easy to find, is is under paragraph *3* and is as follows, given the following:

```
namespace A {
  using namespace Y;
  void f(int);
  void g(int);
  int i;
}
namespace B {
  using namespace Z;
  void f(char);
  int i;
}
namespace AB {
  using namespace A;
  using namespace B;
  void g();
}
```

Buried in the examples is the following:

```
AB::i++; // i is not declared directly in AB so the rules are
         // applied recursively to A and B,
         // S is { A::i , B::i } so the use is ambiguous
         // and the program is ill-formed
```

Comment: I have one question. Is there exist an example besides the example of  ambiguity declaration which does not allow to choose unique declaration?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I do not see such an example and I am not sure if that would even be possible.

Comment: I've understood you. Thanks.